# Angular-CLI import primeng

Tags: angular, import, primeng

I am trying to get primeng working in my angular2 project but have yet to get it working.

Steps taken:

1. Installed: `npm install primeng --save`
2. Added to module

   `import {DialogModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
   @NgModule({... imports: [DialogModule, ...]});`
3. Added stylesheets to `index.html`
4. Added to template:

   `<p-dialog header="Test" [(visible)]="display">
   Content
   </p-dialog>`

   **Note:** `display: boolean = false` in component

I don't get any build or run time errors, nothing happens when I click a button which sets `display = true`.

In my research I have seen a lot of refrences to webpack and system.js and that I have to map it. I cant find those files so I am not sure if it applies to me.

**Edit:** angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.19-3

Comment: Why do you state primeng in ypur title (it was pimeng, I corrected it) yet tag the question primefaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to be taken may help you,

- Shift all your css files of primeng from `index.html` to `angular-cli.json` file. like this

  ```
  "styles": [
      "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
      "../node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.css"
       ....
    ],
  ```

  ....
- Print your variable `display` in html for surety of binding and also try simply setting modal true by default, like this

  ```
   <p-dialog header="Test" [(visible)]="true">....
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to import which module you will use that one is correct.

Your cli.json should look like this. It's just an example by the way.

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
    "assets/layout/css/layout.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
    "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css",
    "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
    "../node_modules/nanoscroller/bin/css/nanoscroller.css",
    "../node_modules/animate.css/animate.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
    "../node_modules/moment/moment.js",
    "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js",
    "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js",
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it to the exports also (to make it visible to the components):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ DialogModule],
  exports: [ DialogModule ]
})
```

Comment: i dont think there is need to list down in the list of `exports` , reason is already `dialogModule` is a module which is being exported by somewhere.

Comment: This is from my working app.  Ignore it if you like.

Comment: haha but this is not valid so pointing out here. anyways never mind

Comment: If I remove the definition from exports, the dialog doesn't work. Have fun.

Comment: Nope, adding it to exports did not fix it :/